# Is there any law in France that gives medical patients a right to refuse treatment?

Tags: health, france

Is there any law in France that protects medical patients?

For example, medication that excessively uses drugs as pain killers may result in bad effects.

Can the family/relatives complain about it? How is the procedure?

I want to know whether it's possible to refuse the use of excessive drugs, on the grounds that it doesn't heal the root of the problem but only to suffer more.

Comment: You have asked two questions in one, which is frowned upon here. I would edit to remove the first, since French patient protection is almost certainly unrelated to nationality or even residence, and focus on the second. I also think the second is more likely to be on topic at http://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you asking about whether and how you can withold/deny/withdraw/discontinue consent for a medical treatment (e.g. pain killers) proposed by the doctor, or, are you asking what the procedure is to bring a legal complaint about treatment which was give in the past?

Comment: [This law for example](https://www.conseil-national.medecin.fr/article/article-36-consentement-du-malade-260) is about informed consent and says what I would have guessed it would say, i.e. that doctors need informed consent from the patient, or from the patient's *proches* (i.e. from their "near", like kin, except that it can mean family or anyone else who the patient has designated as being the person in whom they have "confidence", including e.g. the person's GP -- this designation IMO requires lucidity but not a notary, they can give you a form at the hospital), except in emergency.

Comment: @ChrisW Does it have English version?

Comment: @ChrisW to refuse the use of excessive drugs because it doesn't heal the root of the problem but only to suffer more.

Comment: Google Translate will do an IMO adequate job. See also e.g. http://www.chu-nice.fr/patient-visiteur/vous-informer/droits-du-patient/1963-consentement-du-patient-et-le-refus-de-soins (which is a random hospital explaining it in a more lay language). Note that doctors are allowed to argue in favour of a course of treatment; but I think that the patient (or their next of kin or their "designated trusted person") should (must in principle) be consulted and may say no. Also (if it's in a hospital) one or more of the doctors may speak some English.

Comment: @ChrisW Does it have English version? am now trying to translate by google. Thanks!

Comment: @rusticmystic -- if you have the google chrome browser it should automatically offer to translate the entire page.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a law](https://www.conseil-national.medecin.fr/article/article-36-consentement-du-malade-260) about informed consent.

I won't translate it verbatim, but it says more or less what one might have guessed it would say: i.e. that doctors need informed consent from the patient; or must consult with the patient's *proches*, except in emergency.

The noun *proches* literally means the patient's "nears", which is a word like "kin" except that in this case it can mean family, or it can mean anyone else who the patient has designated as being the person in whom they have "confidence", which could even include e.g. the person's GP -- effecting such a designation doesn't need a notary (but may require lucidity): they can give you a form at the hospital.

The above is *a* law, i.e. one of the laws: there are others -- see e.g. [France passes new end-of-life legislation to alleviate suffering](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/11478999/France-passes-new-end-of-life-legislation-to-alleviate-suffering.html) dated 2015, which also mentions a 2005 law (named [la loi Leonetti](http://sante.lefigaro.fr/social/sante-publique/euthanasie/que-dit-precisement-loi-leonetti)):

> France legalised “passive euthanasia” in 2005, where treatment, needed to maintain life is withheld or withdrawn

I don't know of English transcriptions of these laws, but Google Translate provides an IMO mostly-understandable translation of such web pages. Alternatively it's my experience that in a French hospital you may find that the doctor (or at least, that one of the doctors or nurses) can talk in English.

See also e.g. http://www.chu-nice.fr/patient-visiteur/vous-informer/droits-du-patient/1963-consentement-du-patient-et-le-refus-de-soins (which is a random hospital explaining the "informed consent" and in a more lay language).

Note that doctors may recommend or argue in favour of a course of treatment, and not accept a first refusal, and are for example expected to inform you of the likely consequences of withdrawing from treatment (that's part of your being "informed" so that you can give or refuse informed consent), which I suppose could seem like a refusal on their part; but so far as I know (i.e. in theory, based on the information such as I've referenced here) the patient (or their next of kin or their "designated trusted person") should (must in principle) be consulted and may say no.

As an aside, some people's personal experience has been that sometimes it seems as if some French doctors are more willing to divulge apparently bad news (e.g. a fatal or terminal prognosis) to the patient's kin than to the patient themselves.

---

Reading the small print of Article 36 again isn't entirely clear:

- Clearly the patient has a right to refuse treatment.
- Equally clearly in case of emergency the doctor doesn't need permission before treating.
- What's less clear is whether the the *proches* are allowed to refuse consent if the patient is incapable: what it actually says is that the doctor must "consult" with the kin.

So actually the other http://www.chu-nice.fr/patient-visiteur/vous-informer/droits-du-patient/1963-consentement-du-patient-et-le-refus-de-soins text has this paragraph which gives additional detail:

> **1- Patient hors d’état d’exprimer son refus :**
>
> Lorsque le patient est hors d’état d’exprimer sa volonté, que ce soit du fait d’un état passager limitant ou abolissant tout discernement (toxicomanie…) ou d’un état comateux ou d’inconscience passagère, le médecin doit prévenir la personne de confiance s’il en existe une, ou à défaut un proche.
>
> Face au refus de soins exprimé, au nom du patient, par la personne de confiance, ou un proche, ou par le patient dans ses directives anticipées, le médecin va devoir mettre en place une procédure dite collégiale où l’intervention de la personne de confiance ou du proche n’est que consultative.
>
> Pour prendre la décision de respecter ou non ce refus de soins, le médecin va devoir se concerter avec son équipe médicale et soignante, demander l’avis médical motivé d’un confrère. Une fois la concertation de l’équipe et la consultation du confrère médecin, le médecin prend une décision qui doit prendre en compte l’avis de la personne de confiance ou du proche.

... which says that if the patient isn't in a state to express their will (e.g. drunk, comatose, unconscious) the doctor must notify the patient's "personne de confiance" or failing that someone else close to them. If that person refuses in the name of the patient, then the doctor must put in place a "collegial" process where the intervention of the kin is merely consultative. To decide whether to respect the refusal of treatment the doctor will have to decide in concert with their medical and treatment team and ask advice from a colleague (and then decide, taking advice into account).

In other words, the kin or person of confidence (in other countries may be a.k.a. "guardian")  may refuse treatment and their refusal will be taken into account and yet might not be the final decision -- the final decision might be overruled by a quorum of doctors.

There may also be an "[advanced directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_healthcare_directive)" previously written by the patient. The doctor may ask the patient or kin) whether there is such a directive -- and if there is, then the directive will have some weight that's similar to the weight of a kin's input (i.e. the doctor will consult it, but isn't in every case necessarily bound by it).

Comment: Can the use of excessive drugs be classified as "masked euthanasia"? Can it be done at places outside of the hospitals (ex. home care, retirement place, etc.)?

Comment: "Excessive" sounds wrong by definition i.e. your using the word implies you've decided it's wrong. When someone is e.g. dying of cancer and has ever-increasing pain the prescribing doctor must follow a protocol, prescribing enough pain killer for the pain ... but I think they have to see the renewed/increased pain before increase the prescription ... and in that way the prescription is meant to be appropriate (for the patient's present condition) rather than excessive.

Comment: The answer to the latter question might I guess be "it depends" (perhaps depending e.g. on what care and treatment the patient needs and maybe too how frequently they need to see a doctor) and is I'd guess a question for the kin to put to the doctor. People in France have typically/ideally each chosen a "*medecin traitant*" (their primary physician or family doctor, who refers the patient to specialists when necessary). If you find it difficult to talk to a specialist-doctor a second way is to talk with the *medecin traitant* (part of whose job seems to be  to coordinate care and explain it).

Comment: [This](http://www.europe1.fr/societe/mourir-a-la-maison-un-souhait-complique-a-realiser-1363088) and [this](http://www.slate.fr/lien/65965/mort-france-carte) say that though most people want to die at home, medical treatment (which is more and more complex) can be complicated or impossible to arrange and deliver at home. Here is an English translation of a demographics paper from 2015, [A majority of people would prefer to die at
home, but few actually do so](http://www.ined.fr/fichier/s_rubrique/23908/population.societies.2015.524.die.at.home.en.pdf), FYI, which includes background details.

Comment: In France, there is an organization "SHADE" who is in charge of patients at home care and/or retirement place. It seems that they act as 'a bridge' between patients and doctors. Please enlighten me if necessary, but the increasing use of this drugs is really surprising. Patient looked powerless and sleep most of the day, in fact the patient is a smart and bright person. So, nowadays the person can not think clearly; could just fall asleep when talking.

Comment: I'm not a doctor and don't know the patient or their illness. I guess that unconsciousness isn't necessarily only caused by drugs but could also be caused e.g. by hypoglycemia and/or I don't know what else. Someone once told me that in the old days (before effective medicines were generally available) some people used to kill themselves (or were restrained, to prevent them from killing themselves) because of their pain. One thing to try to understand is why a treatment is prescribed: is it in hope of healing, in the hope of extending life, and/or in the hope of keeping the patient comfortable?

Comment: I haven't found 'SHADE' using Google.

Comment: perhaps it was a wrong term/abbreviation I gave you (because it was only caught up often by my ears), but it is more and less "Système hospitalier  à domicile executive"

Comment: @rusticmystic I don't find that with Google either. The French phrase seems to me unnatural, contrived to make the acronym, yet the acronym only makes sense in English ("shade" isn't a French word). But here [I found the practice (not an organization) described as HAD](https://www.google.fr/search?q=hospitalisation+%C3%A0+domicile). Some people (e.g. Buddhists) deem it better to be lucid and therefore to minimize pain killers, but most people prefer to minimize pain instead. Also it might be possible for kin to stay next to a dying patient's bed 24x7 which can make things easier for everyone.

Comment: Anyone (native English) who could legally lead British nationality elderly with intermediate spoken French, may I be having further contact.

Comment: @rusticmystic There's a http://cancersupportfrance.fr/need-some-help organization who might be able to advise; they link to [this (French) page about 'to know your legal rights'](http://www.e-cancer.fr/Patients-et-proches/Ressources-utiles/Numeros-et-sites-utiles/Vos-droits), at the bottom of which is phone numbers to contact (French) lawyers from the French league against cancer, who might be able to advise. Or Googling for *English lawyer in France* found [this list](http://france.embassy.gov.au/pari/lawyers.html) on the Australian embassy's web site.

Comment: Is there any benevolent organization/foundation in France in the field of law? I've tried on Google, but still got no result.

Comment: @rusticmystic I don't understand that question and I don't know of any such foundations/organizations. You could also try asking on the [expatriates.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: NP. The person has passed away just recently :(